# How to declare a string so that it's length is given by the user in c?

Tags: c, string

So I've been asked to do that, and I did it like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void)
    {        
        int N,i;
        printf("Give the number of char's you want to input.\n");
        scanf("%d",&N);

        char *str = (char*) malloc(N);

        //this segment inputs the char's to the string.
        printf("Input the char's.\n"); 
        for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
           str[i] = getchar();
        }
        str[N] = '\0';
    }
```

Since I am a novince in c,
I would like to know whether there is another/better way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start writing to your character string at `i=0`: `for (i=0;i<N;i++)` and then add the null-terminator manually to `str[N] = '\0'`

Comment: This is not correct C and any compiler that supports the features that you are using should have told you. I don't know from which ancient code you copied that, but `main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt I wrote it myself.I use devc++ but it never complained though

Comment: @Mechanic45, then you should look up the options of your compiler to increase the warning level.

Comment: When you ask a question by giving a bad code and you receive answers that tell you how to write it correctly, DON'T edit your post accordingly, or we won't know how your original question looked like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) ( allowed in C99 and latter ) or use [dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). Your approach is using VLA. You can also do this dynamically as:

```
int N;
printf("Give the number of char's you want to input.\n");
scanf("%d",&N);

char *str = malloc(N+1);
```

---

Side notes:

- Change `main` to its correct signature `int main(void)`.
- Array indexing starts with `0` in C. Initialize `i` to `0` instead of `1` and set the upper bound to `i < N`. Change your `for` loop to

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  
> {
>      str[i] = scanf(" %c");
> } 
> str[N] = '\0';
> ```

- As suggested by [H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063686/how-to-declare-a-string-so-that-its-length-is-given-by-the-user-in-c/21063725?noredirect=1#comment31674930_21063725), do not use `scanf`, particularly with `grtchar`.
  Use [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead.

Comment: +1 but **pretty please** don't encourage the use of `scanf()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any particular reason everybody advises against using the particular limits for, for-loop the way I did?

Comment: ok applied the suggested changes to code.
about the last one though. If I should not use scanf, then which one?

Comment: @Mechanic45; Added a link to the answer.

Comment: Uhm..About malloc.. I get this warning and the program malfunctions.
[Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]

Comment: Include `<stdlib.h>` header.

Answer (score 3):

I believe dynamic memory allocation using such as `malloc()` is a better solution to your problem, that means instead of

```
char str[N+1];
```

you should do

```
char *str = malloc(N+1);
```

And do not forget to free the memory by `free(str);` after you finished use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although could you please explain why dynamic mem alloc is better than VLA?

Comment: @Mechanic45 It's not better. It's different.

Comment: @H2CO3 nop, you can't use VLA with MSVC (maybe with other compilers)

Comment: @Ubiquité Non sequitur. Visual C++ is not a C compiler. You can't use VLAs with **any** C++ compiler, because VLAs are not part of C++. So this has **absolutely nothing** to do with Windows. (Even if VC++ was a C compiler, your argument would still not make sense, since there are other C compilers for Windows as well, for example GCC, which supports C99 and VLAs.)

Comment: Agreed with @H2CO3. There is some difference in between C and Microsoft-C. Compile your code with GCC or Ming on WIN and see the effect.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think before using a language feature it's good to know where you will be able to compile it. You may not want to change your compiler because of VLA

Comment: @Ubiquité Sure thing, but in this case OP won't need to change his compiler -- he is already writing C code (if we can believe the tags on his question). (Also, I know that there **is** a - rarely used - C compiler that comes with Visual Studio, but unfortunately, it doesn't support C99... what a shame!)

Comment: @H2CO3 MSVC rarely used !? Where did you get this strange information ?

Comment: @Ubiquité Not MSVC -- read my comment more carefully. The C compiler that comes with it. People usually use Visual Studio to write C++ code (and consequently, they use its C++ compiler more often).

Comment: @H2CO3 I do prefer VLA compare to malloc/free but I gave a reason why someone could prefer malloc/free to VLA : make portable code

Comment: @Ubiquité I understand your reasoning, and I believe you that it was what you meant. However, you were saying something different.

Answer (score 2):

Well what you're trying to do is supported by C99 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array . And GCC supports this from C90.

But actually this is The Bad Way to implement things. Such arrays are allocated on stack. This may be quite useful because their allocations and deallocations are damn fast, but this approach may lead to e.g. stack overflows.

Usually such tasks are implemented using dynamic allocations. See documentation for malloc http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc and free http://linux.die.net/man/3/free More complete documentation with examples may be found [here](http://info2html.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/info2html-demo/info2html?%28libc.info.gz%29Memory%2520Allocation)

Comment: *But actually this is The Bad Way to implement things*: I disagree until you need large memory spaces.

Comment: Well, you know, I laso like objects allocated on stack. They are fast, they are local, they don't cause memory trashing on deallocation. But in this particular case a user specifies the length of the array. The input string is also user-provided. Both arguments aren't sanitized. Actually this approach is the cause of most cracks and vulnerabilities in the Net. Certainly, I understand that it's just an example code by a novice C programmer. However it's better to teach yourself on carefully throught examples.

Answer (score 2):

A better way is using `fgets()` and suggesting testing user input results.

```
printf("Give the number of char's you want to input.\n");

buf[40]; 
if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL) {
  Handle_EOForIOError();
}
int n;  // Suggest lower case 'n'
if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &n) != 1) Handle_SyntaxError();

char str[n+2];  // OP's VLA

if (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) == NULL) {
  Handle_EOForIOError();
}

// Trim the \n if needed
size_t len = strlen(str);
if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == '\n') str[--len] = '\0';
```